# I need to create a table where summarize several continuous variables by two categorical variables

Tags: gtsummary

In the first figure you can see what I´ve been trying with no success.

["ciclo" and "etnibee" are two categorical variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd1QL.jpg)

In the second figure you can see what I wish I could get...
[Expected Outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQLVU.jpg)

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The table is possible to construct using the various building blocks of tables available in gtsummary. Admittedly, it's not the easiest, though. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'
library(tidyverse)


fun1 <- function(data, variable, by) {
  # extract variable label
  lbl <- attr(data[[variable]], "label") %||% variable
  
  # construct table
  data %>% 
    nest(data = -all_of(by)) %>%
    arrange(.data[[by]]) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
      tbl = 
        tbl_summary(
          data = data, 
          include = variable, 
          missing = "no",
          label = list(as.character(.data[[by]])) %>% setNames(.env$variable)
        ) %>%
        modify_header(stat_0 ~ paste0("**", lbl, "**")) %>%
        modify_table_body(~.x %>% mutate(variable = .env$by)) %>%
        list()
    ) %>%
    pull(tbl) %>%
    tbl_stack(quiet = TRUE)
}

# now stratify all these resulst by another variable
final_tbl <-
  tbl_strata(
    trial, 
    strata = trt,
    ~c("age", "marker") %>%
      # now add multiple variable columns 
      map(function(v) fun1(data = .x, variable = v, by = "grade")) %>%
      tbl_merge() %>%
      modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>